# How to handle ref params when call c# function from ironpython

Tags: c#, python, reference, ironpython, parameters

Recently, I use ironpython as my script engine  in my c# projects, I use it to develop addins as  described in book -"IronPython in Action". But when I call a c# function with ref param,I don't known how to handle it! The c# code like this:

```
public class TestCSharp
{
    public void run(ref byte stop)
    {
        while(!stop)
        {
             // do something
        }
    }
}
```

The ironpython code as bellow:

```
inst = TestCSharp()
stop = System.Byte(0)
t = Thread(...)
// call inst.run() in thread t
inst.run(stop)
// do something
stop = System.byte(1)
```

but inst.run can't stop

anybody know why? If my approach is not right, how to implement my requirement?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

They're [returned as a result tuple](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/dotnet.html#ref-and-out-parameters):

```
>>> d = { "a":100.1, "b":200.2, "c":300.3 }
>>> from System.Collections.Generic import Dictionary
>>> d = Dictionary[str, float](d)
>>> d.TryGetValue("b")
(True, 200.2)
>>> d.TryGetValue("z")
(False, 0.0)
```